# Can't access Mobx object within object properties

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mobx

How could I access property that is located inside an object and that object stored in object

The following console log `console.log(this.props.auth.user)` provides the output below, I am trying to access the role property.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: It should be `this.props.auth.user.role`, since it looks like that's a top-level property of the object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no its a bit more complicated, i attached a picture to show how its coming

Comment: Please do not paraphrase errors. Do you get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined"? If you do, that might suggest that you have a problem with async code. Please add a [mcve]. edit: With your comment update, that is probably not true anymore. But a [mcve] is still needed.

Comment: Assuming the proxy allows you to access `role` in the normal way (which is the default behavior for a proxy), you would access it like that (`this.props.auth.user.role`). If the proxy denies access, or changes how the property looks, we can't help you without knowing how the Proxy is written.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is not related to proxy its a MobX object

Comment: @ArtjomProzorov - It may be a MobX object, but it's **definitely** a Proxy. That's really, really obvious from your console screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mobx.toJS`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/tojson.html#tojs) to convert an observable object to a javascript structure:

**An Example:**

```
const obj = mobx.observable({
    foo: 1,
    bar: 'hello',
  })
const clone = mobx.toJS(obj)
const foo = clone.foo
const bar = clone.bar
```

So, you could do:

```
const user = mobx.toJS(this.props.auth.user)
const role = user.role
```

Comment: Hey ,  user  already is observable in the store , so its coming as props to my component , it show me JS object with values but i cannot still access the actual property  const clone = mobx.toJS(this.props.auth.user);
        console.log(clone.role);

Comment: updated, i cannot even get property from js object, that is weird

Comment: After restarting everything on my end  i was able to successfully refer to role by doing mobx.JS , thank you for your time so much

Comment: @ArtjomProzorov  I am able to access object properties without using `toJS`. Here is the [repo](https://github.com/ajeetshah/react-mobx) I tried. You can check if you want.